# Add post parameters in loop - OkHTTP

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I'm using OkHTTP for making a post request to my server. I know I can build a request like this:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("param1", param1)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```

So what I want to do is to add the parameters dynamically. E.g:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    for (ParamsArray m : requestParams) {
        formBody.add("param1", requestParams.value);
    }
```

But there's no function `add` for a `RequestBody` and I don't know if it is possible to convert a `FormEncodingBuilder` to a `RequestBody`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FormEncodingBuilder` will turn into a `RequestBody` when you build it. Looking at the documentation, something like this ought to work.

```
FormEncodingBuilder formBodyBuilder = new FormEncodingBuilder()
for (ParamsArray m : requestParams) {
    formBodyBuilder.add("param1", requestParams.value);
}
RequestBody body = formBodyBuilder.build()
```

The documentation is available here:
https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/FormEncodingBuilder.html

Comment: Oh, well I better look at the documentation next time - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As of 3.0.0, the [FormEncodingBuilder is gone](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Form and Multipart bodies are now modeled. We've replaced the opaque
>   FormEncodingBuilder with the more powerful FormBody and
>   FormBody.Builder combo. Similarly we've upgraded MultipartBuilder into
>   MultipartBody, MultipartBody.Part, and MultipartBody.Builder.

So replace with FormBody.Builder for these versions.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
FormEncodingBuilder formBodyBuilder = new FormEncodingBuilder();

for (ParamsArray m : requestParams) {
    formBodyBuilder.add("param1", requestParams.value);
}
RequestBody formBody = formBodyBuilder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FormEncodingBuilder

use

```
Builder paramBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
paramBuilder.add("param1","value1");
paramBuilder.add("param2","value2");
RequestBody requestBody = paramBuilder.build();
```